# Galaxy S3 cell standby is eating my battery

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, battery-life, cellular-radio

My battery on my new S3 seems to be being eaten up by the cell standby using more than 50%. 
I appear to get a decent signal on the phone. Does anyone have any idea why this figure would be so high?

Comment: See also: [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29447/16575)

Answer (score 1):

That is terrible! Drains to 50% only in stanby!

Maybe the apps are not really shut off. You can use the free apps - JuiceDefender to save your power. Packed with smart functions, it automatically and transparently manages the most battery draining components, like 3G/4G connectivity and WiFi.

Or you may need to have a external battery to backup. [This one sugegsted:](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006ZTMEZ4)

Small and portable design, Powerful and giant inside. Will be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

XDA recogined contributer bala_gamer has explained and fixed this issue. Check [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1732722) xda-developers thread and [this](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/international-galaxy-s-iii-cell-standby-power-drain-issue-identified/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+xda-developers%2FShsH+%28xda-developers%29) news item.

> It would seem that the issue comes from an error in framework-res.apk.
>   XDA Recognized Contributor bala_gamer explains that the power drain
>   value setting for Cell standby is erroneouslyset to 34 mA (practically
>   impossible) instead of a more reasonable value of 3.4 mA in
>   power_profile.xml within framework-res.apk. He then put together a
>   corrected power_profile.xml, and provided a quick step-by-step guide
>   to pushing the change. Those not excited about messing directly with
>   framework-res.apk can thank Senior Member ausdim for providing a
>   recovery-flashable update.zip.

Don't forget to read the warning and FAQ if any.